# Z-Index without style sheet

Tags: html, css, web

Can you set the Z-Index for an image in HTML without writing or embedding a style sheet? I am uploading some content to a web forum and I need to be able to put some text on top of an image, formatted inside of a table, but the image just gets pushed out of the way. There is no way to "send to back". I have been making minor changes to the HTML itself, but I have been trying to avoid it as the GUI based editor tends to add a lot of extra filler to the HTML and makes it aweful to read.

Comment: This really depends on the forum you're posting to. It may or may not allow CSS to begin with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean using inline style? So something like

```html
<img src="http://path/to/img/" style="position: absolute; z-index: 3" />
```