# z-index style being ignored on embedded video

Tags: css, position, embed, z-index, styling

For some reason I cannot modify the z-index of an embedded video to make it appear in front of an image. I know the beginner's mistake of not applying positioning to said video, and I have tried applying absolute and relative positioning to no avail.
I looked at the question below and I know it is possible to modify z-index with an inline style. Can somebody please explain why my z-index style is being ignored?

[Z-Index without style sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251650/z-index-without-style-sheet)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SDL.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src="img/SDL 4 Final Recompress.jpg"/>
<embed
src="http://blip.tv/play/AwGUv2w"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="669"
height="500" allowscriptaccess="always"
allowfullscreen="true" style="postion:absolute;z-index:2;">
</embed>
<img src="img/Stage-Background.png" style="postion:absolute;z-index:1;"/>

</center> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `wmode="opaque"` to the embed element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your style from `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;`. I don't think it will work for you but it worked for me.

**Update**
And by the way, you put `postion` instead of `position`. Or if you have and existing other css styling inside, you can put `position:relative !important;`

Comment: I cannot believe how stupid that mistake was. I spelled position wrong. I am sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I have flagged this post for deletion